# EF Core 3.1 Owned Entities returning null objects when querying database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-3.1, owned-types

I have a `User` class with an owned entity `PersonalInformation` that contains properties like `FirstName`, `LastName`, `PhoneNumber`, etc.

The `User` class is a table who's `Id` is pulled from another login database `AspNetUsers` that holds all login information.

When I try and read from the database, the `PersonalInformation` object is always `null`, even though data exists in the database. Here's the classes

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public PersonalInformation PersonalInformation { get; set; }
}

public class PersonalInformation
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
    public string OtherPhone { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the configuration

```
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.OwnsOne(x => x.PersonalInformation, pi =>
        {
            pi.Property(x => x.FirstName).HasMaxLength(25);
            pi.Property(x => x.MiddleName).HasMaxLength(25);
            pi.Property(x => x.LastName).HasMaxLength(25);
            pi.Property(x => x.MobilePhone).HasMaxLength(15);
            pi.Property(x => x.HomePhone).HasMaxLength(15);
            pi.Property(x => x.OtherPhone).HasMaxLength(15);
            pi.Property(x => x.WorkPhone).HasMaxLength(15);
        });

        builder.Property(x => x.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(36);
        builder.Property(x => x.LastModifiedBy).HasMaxLength(36);

    }
}
```

[Here's an image of the database table we're pulling from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC9rG.png)

This is the call to the user table

```
var user = await context.Users
    .FindAsync(_currentUserService.UserId);
```

I've also tried this one too

```
var user = await context.Users
    .Include(x => x.PersonalInformation)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == _currentUserService.UserId);
```

When I examine user in the debugger, I see that `User.PersonalInformation` is `null`, even though there's data in the database.

I've looked on here for someone with a similar problem, and they suggested the following. Each did not fix my issue:

1. Add `WithOwner()` to `UserConfiguration` class
2. Add `virtual` to `PersonalInformation` on `User` class (as if it was a navigation property)
3. Add `Include` + `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` to query (as if it was a navigation property)
4. Upgrade to latest version of EF Core (3.1.6 as of this post)

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The `DateTime DateOfBirth` was null in the database which caused the entire object to be null. Once I provided a value in the database, it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem and fixed it with explicit include of related object (used eager loading) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/

Comment: The original question shows that they tried an explicit include (eager loading).